# Converting a C-style for loop that uses division for the step to Swift 3

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift3

I have this loop, decrementing an integer by division, in Swift 2.

```
for var i = 128; i >= 1 ; i = i/2  {
   //do some thing
}
```

The C-style for loop is deprecated, so how can I convert this to Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MartinR's solution is very generic and useful and should be part of your toolbox.

Another approach is to rephrase what you want: the powers of two from 7 down to 0.

```
for i in (0...7).reversed().map({ 1 << $0 }) {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Quite general loops with a non-constant stride can be realized
with [`sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence):

```
for i in sequence(first: 128, next: { $0 >= 2 ? $0/2 : nil }) {
    print(i)
}
```

- *Advantages:* The loop variable `i` is a constant and its scope is
  restricted to the loop body.
- *Possible disadvantages:* The terminating condition must be adapted
  (here: `$0 >= 2` instead of `i >= 1`), and the loop is always executed
  at least once, for the first value.

One could also write a wrapper which resembles the C-style for loop
more closely and does not have the listed disadvantages
(inspired by [Erica Sadun: Stateful loops and sequences](http://ericasadun.com/2016/07/19/stateful-loops-and-sequences/)):

```
public func sequence<T>(first: T, while condition: @escaping (T)-> Bool, next: @escaping (T) -> T) -> UnfoldSequence<T, T> {
    let nextState = { (state: inout T) -> T? in
        guard condition(state) else { return nil }
        defer { state = next(state) }
        return state
    }
    return sequence(state: first, next: nextState)
}
```

and then use it as

```
for i in sequence(first: 128, while: { $0 >= 1 }, next: { $0 / 2 }) {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest that you should use a `while` loop to handle this scenario:

```
var i = 128
while i >= 1
{
    // Do your stuff
    i = i / 2
}
```

Comment: I like to use `i /= 2` over `i = i / 2`.