# Swift C-style loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

```
for (var i = 1; i < 1024; i *= 2) {
    print(i)
}
```

How can this be done with for in loop?

The given solution is for `+=` operator not `*=` operator. Please provide a solution for `*=` thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do it another way? The way you have it is pretty optimal.

Comment: @Bathsheba this way is not possible in Swift 3.

Comment: Similar: [Converting a C-style for loop that uses division for the step to Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903503/converting-a-c-style-for-loop-that-uses-division-for-the-step-to-swift-3) and [Express for loops in swift with dynamic range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070202/express-for-loops-in-swift-with-dynamic-range)

Comment: To be fair I did not find the dupe immediately. The google terms were "swift range step". The selected answer solves this *exact* problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe that one solves it for `+=2` but not `*=2`

Comment: @Bathsheba C style loop is no longer valid in swift 3.

Comment: If I were you I'd add that to the question. To keep charlatans like me away. (But why the deuce would a language committee want to deprecate the C-style loop?!)

Comment: I'm just curious as to why there is only one close vote when this is so obviously a dupe.

Comment: @Bathsheba: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md for the rationale, and links to the discussion. (That does not mean that everybody agreed with the decision :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can do

```
for f in sequence(first: 1, next: { $0 < (1024 / 2) ? $0 * 2 : nil }) {
    print(f)
}
```

The concept of the `sequence` function is described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence).

Printing an infinite list is easy, the code would just be

```
for f in sequence(first: 1, next: {$0 * 2}) {
    print(f)
}
```

Since we want the program to stop at some point, we us the *ternary operator* `?` to terminate the list once we reach the maximum value.
Since the last value we want to print is `512`, the last value we have to double is `256`. For `512` which does not satisfy the condition `< (1024 / 2)` we have `nil` and thereby stop.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's so much clearer than the C-style way. One step forward, two steps back. Have an upvote.

Comment: Note that the C loop (from the question) *excludes* the value 1024. Your code will include that number.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: your stride would produce 1, 3, 5, 7, ... and not  1, 2, 4, 8, 16, .... as desired.

Comment: thanks but your code includes 1024.

Comment: I am illiterate and sorry for that. I misread * as + this whole time. Sincerest apologies for being an ass about it too.

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad. Replace 1024 with 512.

Comment: Now will you remove the down vote please. @MadPhysicist

Comment: I fixed the answer to exclude 1024

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler Thanks for the solution can you explain it to me as I am a beginner.

Comment: Would `for f in stride(from: 0, to: 10) {print(pow(2, f))}` work?

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad Have a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think in Swift 3 you need to add a `by: 1`, but then in will produce the same results, although through different means

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad I extended my answer to explain a bit more. I hope it helps.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler thanks for the explanation. Your link was helpful too.

Comment: This is a little overcomplicated. There's are much more readable solutions, for example: `for i in sequence(first: 1, next: {$0 * 2}).prefix(while: {$0 < 1024})`