# Swift for loop with stride that references itself

Tags: swift

I am trying to replicate this for loop from some JS code.

```
for(var i = 1; i < power; i *=2)
```

But this (obviously) does not work:

```
for i in 1.stride(to: power, step: i*2)
```

I get `unresolved identifier`. Let's say `power` was 256, then I'd expect the sequence for `i` to be `1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128`.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39903503/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/40070202/2976878

Comment: Thanks @Hamish - might be worth making this an answer?

Comment: This code do that:

`let first = 1
let last = 256
let interval = 2
for f in sequence(first: first,
                  next: { $0 * interval < last ? $0 * interval : nil }) {
                    print("Number: \(f)")
}`

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37250498/4763963
Good luck!

Comment: Just use a while loop: `var i = 1; while i < power { // do stuff with i; i *= 2 }`.