# Can you tell a for-loop to conditionally advance by more than one step?

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift4, continue

Consider the following code:

```
let value = "ABCDE"

for letter in value {
    print(letter)
}
```

This prints:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Now consider the hypothetical code that when it finds a '2', it skips 2 forward in the loop. Here's pseudo-code showing what I'm asking...

```
let value = "AB2DE"

for letter in value {

    if letter == "2" {
        continue 2 <-- Does Swift support something similar to this?
    }

    print(letter)
}
```

The above would make the output look like this:

```
A
B
E
```

*Note: Of course I can easily achieve this via managing a skip-counter, then using `continue`, decrementing the counter as I go, or, if the source supports subscripting, as others have suggested I can use a `while` loop where I manage my own index. There are a myriad ways to solve this hypothetical problem, but that's not the intent of my question.*

***My question is specifically to find out if the language natively supports skipping more than one iteration of a for-loop at a time (e.g. something like `continueMany` or `continue x`).***

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170203/swift-3-for-loop-with-increment/37250498

Comment: That's using a fixed interval. I need something conditional.  I think a 'while' loop with my own index is the way to go.

Comment: Are you expecting for the language to decode strings into ints for you? :)

Comment: Also, should the newly decoded int be kept for the remaining characters? Or it should be used only once?

Comment: Also, should we consider only single-digit numbers, or any valid number?

Comment: To me, it seems the question is incomplete

Comment: I've updated the question.  Please check out the last sentence, in bold.  :)

Comment: That makes it clearer, but I think that now you no longer need most of the rest of the question, since it distracts form the actual goal (kinda like a red herring :)

Comment: The difficulty with presenting a made-up, nonsensical scenario is that there often is a good way to solve your _actual_ problem that has [nothing to do with the solution that you're attempting to resolve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/159251).

Comment: There is no 'actual problem'.  That is my entire point.  I'm asking about a language feature (if one exists) and I created an example to illustrate what I was asking.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/39903837/1187415 for a general-purpose for-loop replacement based on `sequence`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR!  Quick question though, it looks like all such iterations are based on numbers, not just a sequence of 'Foo' objects as it's doing integer math to determine if it's a valid value. How can that be used if you have, say, an array of `Foo` objects?

Comment: By the time you're asking about a specific technique, you are in the "present a solution" phase. The problem you're trying to solve is a step or two back: there's some algorithm you're trying to instantiate, and the for loop is one possible way to do that.

Comment: @MarqueIV: You would iterate over the collections *indices,* and conditionally advance it by one or more. Essentially the same as a while-loop as rmaddy suggested below, only that it resembles traditional for-loops, that the iteration variable is a *constant* inside the body, and  its scope is limited to the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't change how a `for-in` loop iterates from within the loop.

A `while` loop with your own index counter is probably the simplest solution in this case. Though you may be able to make use of `sequence(first:next:)` in a `for-in` loop.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you elaborate on `sequence(first:next:)`?

Comment: It's covered in answers at the link provided by @Cristik in the first comment below your question. And of course you can see its documentation.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't notice that as when I saw the question was asking something different, I skipped it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `while` loop. Due to the way string index advancement work in Swift, this is a little complicated compared to many other languages:

```
let value = "AB2DE"

var index: String.Index? = value.startIndex
while let charIndex = index, charIndex < value.endIndex {
    let letter = value[charIndex]

    if let digit = Int(String(letter)) {
        index = value.index(charIndex, offsetBy: digit, limitedBy: value.endIndex)
    } else {
        index = value.index(after: charIndex)
        print(letter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a way to solve the demonstrated problem, but I'm more asking about what the language natively supports. That's why I put the caveat up top.  Starting to think the answer is 'Swift doesn't provide native support for skipping more than one iteration'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the last paragraph in the question is **no** - Swift doesn't have a `continue N`-like statement.

You can use some other language constructs, though, to achieve similar results. Using `reduce` to carry the number if elements to skip is one of them:

```
_ = value.reduce(0) { skip, char in
    // skip while we need to
    guard skip <= 0 else { return skip - 1 }
    // attempt to get a new skip count
    let skip = Int(String(char)) ?? 0
    if skip <= 0 {
        // do the actual work
        print(char)
    }
    // decrement the skip count
    return skip - 1
}
```

Or, a more imperative approach, would be to extend `Iterator` with a `skip` method, and use the iterator for walking through the collection (a `for` loop over a collection is just a sugar syntax over walking over an iterator) :

```
extension IteratorProtocol {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func skip(_ n: Int) -> Element? {
        guard n > 0 else { return next() }
        return skip(n-1)
    }
}

var it = value.makeIterator()
while let char = it.next() {
    if let n = Int(String(char)) {
        it.skip(n)
    } else {
        print(char)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct your custom "skipping" sequence, using a provided `Element -> Int?` predicate to

- if `nil`: don't skip next iteration, or
- if `.some(number)`: skip next `number` iterations

And thereafter use this construct to iterate over your sequence (`value`) and conditionally jump forward.

E.g.:

```
struct SkippingSequence<T: Sequence>: IteratorProtocol, Sequence {
    var iterator: T.Iterator
    let skipPredicate: (T.Element) -> Int?
    // skipPredicate:
    // - nil means no skip,
    // - .some(number) means to skip next 'number' of iterations.
    init(_ collection: T, _ skipPredicate: @escaping (T.Element) -> Int?) {
        self.iterator = collection.makeIterator()
        self.skipPredicate = skipPredicate
    }

    mutating func next() -> T.Element? {
        var n = iterator.next()
        if let skipNumIterations = n.flatMap({ skipPredicate($0) }) {
            for _ in 0..<skipNumIterations { n = iterator.next() }
        }
        return n
    }
}
```

Applied for you example:

```
let collection = "AB2DEF3HIJK"
for letter in SkippingSequence(collection, { Int(String($0)) }) {
    print(letter)
} /* A
     B
     E (skipped 2, D)
     F
     J (skipped 3, H, I)
     K */
```

The `skipPredicate` naming doesn't really explain its purpose, and could be renamed to something with better semantics.